# db:schema:dump on RDS with mysql. Error: Could not dump table "" because of following NoMethodError undefined method `type' for "int(11)":String

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

**Setup:**

> rails: 4.2.5.1
>   ruby: 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]
>   windows 7 environment

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: "database"
  username: "name"
  password: "password"
  host: "host"
  port: 3306 

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: "database"
  username: "name"
  password: "password"
  host: "host"
  port: 3306
```

I am trying to use an existing mysql database on RDS. I created a new project  using
`rails new "app"` and then attempted to get the database schema.
When I run
`ruby bin\rake db:schema:dump` the output in my *schema.rb* file is filled with the same error for every table in the database:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define() do
# Could not dump table "test" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `type' for "int(11)":String
end
```

I first thought that maybe it was because int(11) was a 64 bit integer, but later learned that the "11" in int(11) refers to the display size, and that it is still a 32 bit integer.

Can anyone explain why this is happening or why ruby doesn't recognize the 32 bit integer type for the primary key column.

Comment: better show your migration instead of  `database.yml`

Comment: I don't have a migration for this database yet. I had the assumption that I needed to dump the database's schema in order to create a migration for my rails project. I have been following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@kitsched/starting-a-ruby-on-rails-project-from-existing-data-7dda5044c85f#.27klrlmn2) as a guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get rid of this error by making the following changes to my Gemfile.

```
gem 'mysql2', '~>0.3.13'
#gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'
```

Then I ran `bundle install` to update my gems.

I am still not sure why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have a field named "type" in your database.
"type" is a reserved word in rails(sepecially for database).

Solution : change the name of this field

Ex: "type" => "typemore"

[check this](http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this and see if it helps.

Comment: It does not appear that I have any field names named type in my database, so I do not think this is the issue. But, I do appreciate the list of reserved words in Ruby. That will save me headaches in the future.